# Cannot access property from a method added to a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties

My program uses `MethodType` to add methods to a class. The trouble is that when the code attempts to access a property, it gets a property object instead of getting the property value. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from types import MethodType

from ev3dev2.sensor import *
from ev3dev2.sensor.lego import LightSensor

# methods that extend the class
def set_calibration(self,min_value,max_value):
    self.min_value = min_value
    self.max_value = max_value
    self.value_range = max_value - min_value

def read_calibrated(self):
    value = self.reflected_light_intensity
    print(value)
    return 100 * ( value - self.min_value ) / self.value_range

LightSensor.set_calibration = MethodType( set_calibration, LightSensor )
LightSensor.read_calibrated = MethodType( read_calibrated, LightSensor )

# create class instance
light_left  = LightSensor(INPUT_2)
light_left.set_calibration( 20, 60 )

print(light_left.reflected_light_intensity)
print(light_left.read_calibrated())
```

When I run the program, it produces the following output and error:

```
59.1
<property object at 0xb69f3fc0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./property_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(light_left.read_calibrated())
  File "./property_test.py", line 17, in read_calibrated
    return 100 * ( value - self.min_value ) / self.value_range
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'property' and 'int'
```

I also tried using this:

```
def read_calibrated(self):
    # use underscore to get property value
    value = self._reflected_light_intensity
    print(value)
    return 100 * ( value - self.min_value ) / self.value_range
```

But that generated an error: `AttributeError: type object 'LightSensor' has no attribute '_reflected_light_intensity'`

So, back to the original code, why does `light_left.reflected_light_intensity` return a number, but `self.reflected_light_intensity` return a property object?

More importantly, how do I access the property value from `read_calibrated()`?

Python version is 3.5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding methods to a class instead of an instance object, you can simply hook it by `LightSensor.set_calibration=set_calibration`. `MethodType` is for adding a bound method to a class instance.

```
class LightSensor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.min_value = 1
        self.max_value = 2
        self.value_range = None
        self._reflected_light_intensity = 3

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"min: {self.min_value}, " \
               f"max: {self.max_value}, " \
               f"value_range: {self.value_range}, " \
               f"reflected_intensity: {self._reflected_light_intensity}"

def set_calibration(self,min_value,max_value):
    self.min_value = min_value
    self.max_value = max_value
    self.value_range = max_value - min_value

def read_calibrated(self):
    value = self._reflected_light_intensity
    print(value)
    return 100 * ( value - self.min_value ) / self.value_range

LightSensor.set_calibration = set_calibration
LightSensor.read_calibrated = read_calibrated

a = LightSensor()
a.set_calibration(20,60)
print (a)
print (a.read_calibrated())

b = LightSensor()

print (b)
```

Result:

```
min: 20, max: 60, value_range: 40, reflected_intensity: 3
3
-42.5
min: 1, max: 2, value_range: None, reflected_intensity: 3
```